# After installing LAMP properly, why port number 8080 is required to enter php files under /var/www?

Tags: php, apache, virtualbox, lamp

I installed *LAMP* properly in *Ubuntu 14.04 LTS*.

I created a simple test webpage named *index.php* which includes the following:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

This file is located  under `/var/www/`

When I open chrome in Linux, and enter in the address bar:

```
http://localhost/index.php -> the php page is not shown, and I get an error saying "Page Not Found".
```

However, When enter in the address bar:

```
http://localhost:8080/index.php -> the php page is shown properly.
```

I also configured the following on my virtual box:

[image]

I did this port forwarding because Lynda.com says:

"
VirtualBox's default networking mode is Network Address Translation, or NAT for short, where VirtualBox's networking engine maps traffic to and from the VM. In NAT mode, by default, the guest virtual machine is unreachable from the network, including your computer and browser. Instead, VirtualBox can make selected services available to the network outside the guest by listening to traffic on certain ports from the host and resending all the packets to the guest on the same or different port. This technique is known as port forwarding and the controls to do it are built right into VirtualBox.
By default, VirtualBox doesn't forward any port, which will make it impossible to access the server. 
"

Please answer the following questions:

1. Why only when I enter 8080, the php page is shown properly? I would like just to enter localhost/index.php, how can I do it?
2. If I don`t need any interaction between host and guest, and I would like just to write code in the VM Linux, there is no need to configure any port forwarding. Correct?
3. Lynda.com says that port forwarding is required so that VirtualBox can access the Web Server. 
   IMO, this is wrong, because once I install and configure apache on VM Linux, it just works (even without this port forwarding). So I guess, the input in Lynda.com is wrong? do you agree?

Please answer each question separately.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go to your apache config file httpd.conf located where you installed your apache and search for ":8080", change it to ":80", that will do the job

Comment: Hi, in Ubuntu its in "/etc/apache2/ports.conf, and there I have "Listen 80" and "Listen 8080".

Comment: Check this one "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf" at top see which port is VirtulHost

Comment: Hi, I checked the file, and it says: "<VirtualHost *:80>". So I changed it to "<VirtualHost *:8080>", restart the apache2 service and now it works properly!!! Thanks. So I now learned that once you configure port forwarding on VirtualBox, it`s important to set the virtual port not only on apache2/ports.conf but ALSO on the file you mentioned. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Check the server configuration, seems like you have 2 virtual hosts set up
one on port 80 and another one on port 8080 (which it's root folder is '/var/www')

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html